# How fast did the 2.5 tribes build their new cities?

Tags: commentaries, mattos

I can't find a clear timeline of the events that preceded the conquest but in a short recap:

1. Gad and Reuben asked to settle in Transjordan
2. Moses agrees and offers them to build cities(?) and fences: "בְּנוּ־לָכֶם עָרִים לְטַפְּכֶם וּגְדֵרֹת לְצֹנַאֲכֶם וְהַיֹּצֵא מִפִּיכֶם תַּעֲשׂוּ׃" - "Build towns for your children and sheepfolds for your flocks, but do what you have promised." (Num 32,24)
3. They built numerous cities: "וַיִּבְנוּ בְנֵי־גָד אֶת־דִּיבֹן וְאֶת־עֲטָרֹת וְאֵת עֲרֹעֵר׃ וְאֶת־עַטְרֹת שׁוֹפָן וְאֶת־יַעְזֵר וְיָגְבֳּהָה׃ וְאֶת־בֵּית נִמְרָה וְאֶת־בֵּית הָרָן עָרֵי מִבְצָר וְגִדְרֹת צֹאן׃", etc (ibid 34-42)

Those tribes totaled over 100K **families** with a population of probably reaching the current size of Jerusalem (600K, given 4 kids per household).

Completion of those cities must have preceded the conquest, which occurred only a couple of months later.

What is called "a city" that they built? And how did they build those cities so fast?

Comment: The cities existed already, but had been conquered in the war with Og/Sichon. They were just fixing things up.

Comment: @DoubleAA I thought about it but what, did they cleanse all the habitants? Where do you see in the Torah that the verb לבנות means conquer?

Comment: I didn't say לבנות means conquer. It means fix up.